# how to check if a string is matched with another string

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I saved some user information in .txt file. every time when application launches it checks some specific things, like device id is same as saved or not? 2 type of returns are possible from device id with some character differences.

if i saved this string "pWch7r1fzu tILmQIMjIylBZxJk=" in txt file. i want to make this accepted by application if device id return this string "pWch7r1fzu+tILmQIMjIylBZxJk=" or this string "pWch7r1fzu tILmQIMjIylBZxJk=".

clearly, i have no idea how to achieve this. i have tried index of and instr. they are seems to be fine. like if string matches its return zero and if not -1.

but if device id is this "hfhejkfnenknBG+hhhh" it's returns -1 as well. i do not want it to accept by application.

finally what i want is to get exact string.  differences of one or two char is okay not more than that.

Comment: What code are you using that returns the different strings? Also it's worth noting that the ID will not change on a phone, so I'm not sure why you need to do this in the first place.

Comment: @Peter Torr - MSFT  yes. device id will not change. what i was trying to prevent user to use another phone's text file in to his own. application will get his device id. will make a match with saved device id in text file and verify if true or false.

Comment: There is no way to get the file off the device for a Store-deployed app. But still curious what code you have that gives the different results.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT - I'm not 100% sure this is true if the app is deployed to the SD card in WP8.1?

Comment: Content on the SD card is encrypted with a key specific to that phone. If you try and use the card in another phone (or even reset the current phone and try and use the same card) it won't work.

Comment: i think you can get the file off the device for a Store-deployed app by using windows phone power tools.

Comment: i think i have not make myself clear? basically i have registration process for the application. i use registration code to validate the user. i want to prevent one registration code not to work on another device. for this i mixed device id in the registration code. when application launches it will check for device id and registration code. if device id does not match it fails or pass. so my question is only this? is there any way to check if a string matched to given string? please remember that device id can contains a white space in between.

Comment: Your questions is still not very clear. "How to check if a string matched to a given string?" `string.Compare` function. How to ignore whitespace? Use `Trim` or `string.Replace` on your input string. Now what's your actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case string `a` being the given string and `b` being the to be matched string.

```
        string a = "abcdefghi";
        string b = "abcdefghi";

        char[] c = a.ToCharArray();
        char[] d = b.ToCharArray();

        if(b.Take(b.Length).SequenceEqual(a))
            {
                 // success
            }
```

Comment: What if b=abcdef+ghi and i want to make it success? Or b=abcdefg hij"

Comment: @Pandey `b.Replace("+", "").Replace(" ", "")` or use regex to remove and then compare the strings.